# How to let a 'charge' be a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Definiton: If $\mathbb{X}$ is a $\sigma$ algebra of subsets of a set $\mathbb{X}$, then a **real-valued** (which means it can be positive, negative, or 0) function $\lambda$ defined on $\mathbb{X}$ is said to be a **charge** in case $\lambda(\emptyset)$=0 and $\lambda$ is countably additive.

Question: If $\mu$ is a charge on $\mathbb{X}$, let $\pi$ be defined for $E \in \mathbb{X}$ by:

$\pi(E)=$ Sup{$\mu(A):A \subset E, A \in \mathbb{X}$ }

Show that $\pi$ is a measure.

=============================

I stuck on how to prove $\pi$ is non negative. My idea is to split $\pi$ into $\pi^+$ and $\pi^-$. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\pi(E)=\sup\{\mu(A):A\subset E,\ A\in X\}\ge\mu(\emptyset)=0.$

Comment: Thank you! Now it seems trivial lol